# Pre-caching downloads for Chef when using Vagrant

Tags: java, chef-infra, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant and Chef to automate the setup of a development node. I need Oracle Java installed which unfortunately can no longer be downloaded from Oracle automatically:

> IMPORTANT NOTE As of 26 March 2012 you can no longer directly download
>   the JDK from Oracle's website without using a full-fledged browser.
>   For that reason, the java::oracle recipe forces you to set up a
>   private repository accessible by HTTP. It is best to override the
>   dummy URL using a role.

I'd like to bundle the downloaded JDK with my Vagrantfile so that it can be installed automatically without having to publish the JDK on an internal web server. Is there a way that I can inject the file into chef-solo's file cache so that it's found when the recipe is installed?

It doesn't look like the file_cache_path attribute is supported by the chef-solo recipe. I had thought to set this to a folder that's shared by Vagrant, but that doesn't appear to work.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with the current Vagrant version. I've modified the chef provisioner to enable this, but it needs to be cleaned up before I can make a pull request. In the meantime, if anybody comes up with a way that works without patching Vagrant, I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: I'm happy to accept such a pull request into Vagrant. :) Post it up and I'll review.

Comment: @Mitchell I'll try to get it cleaned up and submitted over the weekend.

Comment: What about creating a special cookbook, putting there the file you want java be installed from (into files/default/). And run the java  installation from the recipe using `cookbook_file` and `execute`?

Answer (score 0):

How we have addressed this issue for a number of packages we install is to create a local squid proxy server used by instances we spin up with Vagrant.

The first time we pull down packages, it run as you would expected. But on the following runs, things are cached locally and run much more quickly.

Of course this doesn't address your specific issue with Oracle JDK, since you cannot download it as part of a recipe.

Answer (score 0):

Use the community java cookbook and set

```
override['java']['oracle']['accept_oracle_download_terms'] = true
```

This is how I have installed java on all servers.